# ag-grid - Cannot get rid of Column Side Bar

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to remove the Columns side bar in ag-grid doing this:

```
<bi-grid id="entitySelectGrid" sideBar="false" [rowData]="(rowData$ | async)">
```

bi-grid is my companies grid that uses ag-grid, btw.

But it is still there. How do I remove the side bar completely?

Answer (score 0):

html for the page that uses the grid:

```
<bi-grid id="entitySelectGrid" [showSideBar]="false" [rowData]="(rowData$ | async)">
```

.ts for the grid:

```
  @Input() showSideBar = true;
```

html for the ag-grid:

```
[sideBar]="showSideBar"
```